# macOS Data Protection without FileVault

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, macos, filevault

I'm running macOS 10.14, and have encountered a problem which prevents me from enabling FileVault. As best as I can determine, there are no free and convenient alternatives for full disk encryption, which has left me to devise other ways to secure my data.

Would it work to store the user account within an encrypted volume created in disk utility/VeraCrypt? This must be better than nothing, but how would it compare to FileVault or other full disk encryption software in terms of security? Critical files/folders would be individually encrypted anyway, but what sort of situations would I be vulnerable to that FileVault would prevent, and how plausible are they?

Edit: If I try to enable FileVault in settings, then it just doesn't respond. Using terminal, I'm met with the following error message.

```
Error: A problem occurred while trying to enable FileVault. (-69594)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on the problem that prevents you from enable FileVault ? You can store files in an partition outside user folder, but you can't move all the files to there. I don't know any other full disk encryption. Currently VeraCrypt don't support full disk encryption for OSX.